# Ant Task to Generate an XML Sample Document from XSD

Tags: java, xml, ant, xsd

I need to generate sample XML documents from XSD's, but I cannot find an Apache Ant task to automate this process. Has anyone come across such task?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this type of functionality exists within Ant or any of the Ant-Contrib tasks.  Ant can validate the XML and schema, but Ant is not a test data generation tool.

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of an ant task to generate a sample document from an XSD, you could use the [ant Java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) to call a program such as [xsd2inst](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/guide/tools.html#xsd2inst) ([source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xmlbeans/trunk/src/tools/org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/xsd2inst/)):

> ### xsd2inst (Schema to Instance Tool)
>
> Prints an XML instance from the specified global element using the
>   specified schema.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> xsd2inst schemafile.xsd -name globalElementName
>
> **Options**
>
> schemafile.xsd The schema file defining the element to print.
>   **-name** The name of the global element globalElementName — The local name of the global element to use as the root of the printed instance.